# ‘react-native run-android’ isn't working on Genymotion but it work on android studio AVD

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

[‘react-native run-android’ isn't working on Genymotion but it work on android studio AVD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a53UB.png)

Comment: click the question to show the tips picture[i can't post the picture yet]

Comment: suggestions are already there in the image. did you try them?

Comment: try this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#method-2-connect-via-wi-fi. If the node is running on same system you could just add localhost:8081/

Comment: Press cmd + m,  for dev menu